# google spreadsheet importxml function on specific searching outside of a table / list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

id like to extract word from webs, specifically restaurant ratings from a website,
e.g., "https://tabelog.com/tw/osaka/A2701/A270202/27018948/" extracting 3.43 from the line:
3.43

since it is not a table/title nor a list, i am not sure if google spreadsheet is capable of doing that.

i tried to brute force tables and lists but it doesnt work somehow, the //title command works tho
just not sure about if spreadsheet is capable of extracting specific numbers from search

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=importxml("https://tabelog.com/tw/osaka/A2701/A270202/27018948/","/html/body/article/header/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/b")
```